# ansible kubectl wait for nodes to be READY

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

Is there any existing ansible module I can use for the following.
I can wait for `kubectl get nodes` `STATUS`=`Ready`?

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master1   NotReady   master    42s       v1.8.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know any existing module for this. you can do something like this.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Wait for nodes to be ready
    shell: "/usr/bin/kubectl get nodes"
    register: nodes
    until:      
      - '" Ready "  in nodes.stdout'      
    retries: 6
    delay: 2
```

Answer (score 10):

### The `kubectl wait` command

Kubernetes supports the use of [kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) from version v1.11.
It waits for a specific condition on one or many resources.

Using the kubectl wait command with ansible tasks:

```
  - name: Wait for all k8s nodes to be ready
    shell: kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready nodes --all --timeout=600s
    register: nodes_ready

  - debug: var=nodes_ready.stdout_lines
```

If you want to check the condition for some particular nodes only, you can use a `--selector` instead of `--all` like this:

```
  - name: Wait for k8s nodes with node label 'purpose=test' to be ready
    shell: kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready nodes --selector purpose=test --timeout=600s
    register: nodes_ready

  - debug: var=nodes_ready.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a specific node to be ready you can do this. In this case it will check if the current node is ready.

```yaml
- name: Wait for node to be ready
  become: yes
  ansible.builtin.shell: $([[ $(kubectl get node $(cat /etc/hostname) -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}') == "True" ]])
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: kubelet_ready
  until: kubelet_ready.rc == 0
  retries: 60
  delay: 3
```