# kubectl wait for nodes to be READY command

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

As per the post here [ansible kubectl wait for nodes to be READY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438010/ansible-kubectl-wait-for-nodes-to-be-ready)
Tried to use below command in the bash script:
**kubectl wait node --all --for condition=ready --timeout=600s**

It intermittently gives below error:
**No resources found
error: no matching resources found**

Because of this the code deployment pipelines are failing. Can someone help on this?

Comment: what kubernetes version are you using ?  what is the output of `kubectl get node`

Comment: kubernetes 1.21.kubectl wait node command fails and then pipeline get failed. But when I connect to the cluster and check kubectl get nodes command it shows the correct output..